# XSL: How can I limit table output to one page

Tags: xslt, pdf

I have a business requirement where I am rendering table data in a PDF.  The requirement is that the contents of the table must not exceed one page including header/footer.  Each row of the table can vary in height so it's not as simple as just limiting the number of rows to output.  How it works now is that the table contents spill over to as many pages as are needed to render the table.

Does anyone know how I can limit the output of a table to just one page?  BTW, I pretty new to xsl and xsl-fo.

Thank you much!

Comment: What do you mean by "limit"? You have no explanation as what you want to do. Cut it off? shrink it? Please rephrase the question providing clear details as to what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

Without stating what you want explicitly, if you just wish to cut off the overflow you have several ways. Since its only one page, I would not bother with doing header/footer regions at all. I would place all the content in absolutely positioned block-containers the size you wish.

For the "middle" one, put the table inside the block-container and set overflow="hidden" on it.

I tested this with both RenderX XEP and Apache FOP, works perfect to clip off the overflow.

Like this:

```
<fo:page-sequence master-reference="first">
    <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
        <fo:block-container position="absolute" top="3in" left="1in" height="1in" width="7in" overflow="hidden" border="1pt solid black">
            <fo:block>
                <fo:table border="solid 1pt blue">
                    <fo:table-column column-number="1" column-width="1.25in"/>
                    <fo:table-column column-number="2" column-width="3in"/>
                    <fo:table-body>
                        <fo:table-row border="solid 1pt red">
                            <fo:table-cell >
                                <fo:block>1.25in</fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block>3in</fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                        </fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-row>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block>1.25in</fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block>3in</fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                        </fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-row>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block>1.25in</fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block>3in</fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                        </fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-row>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block>1.25in</fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block>3in</fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                        </fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-row>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block>1.25in</fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block>3in</fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                        </fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-row>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block>1.25in</fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block>3in</fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                        </fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-row>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block>1.25in</fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block>3in</fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                        </fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-row>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block>1.25in</fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block>3in</fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                        </fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-row>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block>1.25in</fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block>3in</fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                        </fo:table-row>
                    </fo:table-body>
                </fo:table>
            </fo:block>

        </fo:block-container>
    </fo:flow>
</fo:page-sequence>
```